# In SAS how do I make proc means use an informat I have defined to create the statistics?

Tags: sas

```
data abc;
  a = 1; output;
  a = 99; output;
run;

proc format; 
  invalue abc
    99 = .
    other = _same_;

      value abc
    99 = .
    other = _same_;
run;


proc means data = abc;
    format a abc.;
    informat a abc.;
    var a;
run;
```

I would expect the above code to give me a mean of 1 for the variable a. But it doesn't, in proc means it doesn't seem to want to use the format I have defined. Is there an option I can turn on to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my knowledge, formats will work to display the values. formats will not consider into any analysis.

SD.

Answer (score 4):

formats and informats don't work that way. informats change the incoming data before it gets saved in a sas data set. formats change the way data is presented for output, but the underlying data remains unchanged. additionally, formats don't apply to calculations.

you might try something like this?

```
data abc;
  a = 1; output;
  a = 99; output;
run;

data def;
  set abc;
  if a = 99 then a = .N;
run;

proc means data = def;
    var a;
run;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can use the format statement in a proc means or proc summary to apply to variables in the CLASS statement in order to determine how to group them (unless the /groupinternal option is applied to the class statement).  For example, the below code will group the date values into monthly buckets:

    proc means data=dailynumbers;
      class my_date_field;
      format my_date_field month.;
      var sales;
      output out=smry sum=;
    run;